# HTML <a> tag's download attribute override for PDFs

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes
This "download" tag's attribute causes PDF files to be saved, instead of being opened in browser. Can I override this behavior for PDF files to be opened in browser instead? Chrome/Windows 10 ent/ non domain joined so "Open certain file types automatically after downloading" does not work.

Comment: @KJ OP says the computer is not on a domain. It appears they are running Windows 10 Enterprise on a personal computer.

Comment: I don't believe that is how a non-domain-joined computer functions KJ. No domain means the policies applied to the computer originate from the computer itself, with no outside authority or trust enforcing policies. Also, while I prefer Edge to Chrome, Edge is free and doesn't require a license. I have generally found Edge and Chrome's PDF handling functions to be equivalent or equal. Setting names are slightly different, but they generally behave the same way for the various ways PDFs are served online.

Comment: This is Windows 10 Enterprise version. This Windows machine is not domain joined. Chrome also has enterprise package, which obeys GPOs from admx templates. However, not every policy from them works in non-domain joined machine.  This means, that chrome somehow checks if machine is either Domain or MDM joined, and if not, it refuses some policies, they cannot be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding that you're looking to remove the `download` attribute
from the `a` link tag.

This is possible by using the free Chrome extension
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

Tampermonkey injects JavaSvript code into the loaded HTML page,
that execute just after the page is loaded in order to modify the page.
These pieces of code are called "userscripts".

Here is an example of an (untested) userscript to remove the
`download` attribute from all `a` tags:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove Ping Attribute
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Removes the download attribute from all <a> tags
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (const link of links) {
        link.removeAttribute('download');
    }
})();
```

You may limit the userscript to certain websites using regex expressions.

Tampermonkey is a fork of Greasemonkey, and you may find more
information in the webpage
[Greasemonkey Tutorials](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials).